# Using DatastoreIO to save entities of different kinds to datastore in Dataflow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to write entities of different kinds to datastore using DatastoreIO.v1().write().

In my transform function `UpsertStoreItemEntityFn extends DoFn<String, Entity` I am creating '`Entity`' objects conditionally as below:

```
  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) throws Exception {
    IngestionJobRecord jobRecord = convertIntoIngestionJobRecord(processContext.element());

    String validRecordMsg = isRecordValid(jobRecord);
    if (validRecordMsg.isEmpty()) {
      processContext.output(makeSuccessRecordEntity(jobRecord));
    } else {
      processContext.output(makeErrorRecordEntity(validRecordMsg, jobRecord));
    }
  }


private Entity makeErrorRecordEntity(String errorMessage, IngestionJobRecord jobRecord) {
   Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder();

   // All created entities have the same ancestor Key.
   Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey("MyService.ErrorRecordEntity", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
   keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(tenantId);
   entityBuilder.setKey(keyBuilder.build());
   ..
   ..
}

private Entity makeSuccessRecordEntity(StoreItemEntity storeItemEntity) {
  Entity.Builder entityBuilder = Entity.newBuilder();

  // All created entities have the same ancestor Key.
  Key.Builder keyBuilder = makeKey("MyService.SuccessRecordEntity", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  keyBuilder.getPartitionIdBuilder().setNamespaceId(tenantId);

  entityBuilder.setKey(keyBuilder.build());
  ..
  ..
}
```

As you can see, I am setting different 'kind' for both entities. The problem is that when this line in the pipeline:

```
.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId("myProject"));
```

gets executed, then entities of only one of the kinds are written to the datastore.

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or this is a limitation of DatastoreIO that doesn't allow entities of different kinds to be allowed to be written together.

If this is not possible, is there some other way in which I can write both entity kinds to datastore in one single step in dataflow?

Any pointers much appreciated!

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Thanks Abhishek; we are getting in contact with the Datastore client team and looking into this.

Comment: @Abhishek it should be possible to write to multiple kinds, there is no restriction. Do you see any error in the logs or its just that the data is not present?

Comment: You can try splitting the output into two pcollections and then having a different `Datatstore.write` step for each pcollection: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-outputs